# Binary search tree node deletion

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, nodes

I am implementing a function for the node removal from the binary search tree.
The prototype of the function is set and I can't change it, it is a school assignment.
My code:

```
typedef struct tBSTNode {
    char Key;                                                                 
    struct tBSTNode * LPtr;                                
    struct tBSTNode * RPtr;  
} *tBSTNodePtr; 

void BSTDelete (tBSTNodePtr *RootPtr, char K) {
  tBSTNodePtr *tmp;

  if (*RootPtr != NULL) {
    if (K < (*RootPtr)->Key)
        BSTDelete(&(* RootPtr)->LPtr, K);
    else if (K > (*RootPtr)->Key)
        BSTDelete(&(* RootPtr)->RPtr, K);
    else {
            if ((* RootPtr)->LPtr == NULL) {
                /* there is only right branch or none*/
                tmp = RootPtr;
                *RootPtr = (* RootPtr)->RPtr;
                free(*tmp);
                *tmp = NULL;
            }
            else if ((* RootPtr)->RPtr == NULL) {
                /* there is only left branch or none*/
                tmp = RootPtr;
                *RootPtr = (* RootPtr)->LPtr;
                free(*tmp);
                *tmp = NULL;
            }
            else
                /* there are both branches, but that is for another topic*/
        }
    }
}
```

This code works correctly just in case when there are no branches connected to the node I am deleting. I expect that there is a problem with ***tmp = NULL;** line and I am losing my address to the rest of the branch but on the other hand if this line isn't included I am getting a SEGFAULT and I am trying to figure out why.

EDIT:

ok, now I know where the mistake was. It is stupid mistake, I should have used **tBSTNodePtr tmp;** instead of **tBSTNodePtr *tmp;**

Answer (score 1):

you have problems with using pointers. If we have `sometype *ptr` and we check if this ptr adresses some space we write `(ptr!=NULL)`.
`*ptr` is refering to the value itself, for example to your structre.
Read more about pointer types in C.

Comment: Yes I know the concept of using pointers in C and I am using it as you can see.But there is a problem in a pointer logic and your answer doesn't clear anything

Comment: Oh, excuse me. I did not notice the '*' in typedef.

Comment: I think I found out. It is the wrong logic. If there is neither left nor right child, you enter both ifs and free something twice. What is said below is very right and it is the key for the question. But I guess you should add `&& (* RootPtr)->otherside != NULL' in condition, so that your program work more correct.

Answer (score 0):

your logic for deleting is wrong

```
 if ((* RootPtr)->LPtr == NULL) {
                /* there is only right branch or none*/
                tmp = RootPtr;
                *RootPtr = (* RootPtr)->RPtr;
                free(*tmp);
                *tmp = NULL;
            }
```

in this code you are deleting the required node but not adding the child root of that node

```
 if ((* RootPtr)->LPtr == NULL) {
                /* there is only right branch or none*/
                tmp = RootPtr;
                *RootPtr = (* RootPtr)->RPtr;
                free(*tmp);
                *tmp = NULL;
                insert(RootPtr);  //insert the child node again in the tree
            }
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to call another functions like insert() so I need to work just with the code I have shown